# WiX: how to install created patch in REINSTALL=ALL by default?

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I have generated a patch.msp file using wix tools and the when I install it via command line using the following command, all components of my app get updated.

**Install patch.msp file via command line works perfect!**

```
msiexec.exe /p patch.msp /l*vx patch.log /qb REINSTALL=ALL REINSTALLMODE=omusa
```

but when a user installs the patch.msp file using Windows Explore (basically double clicking on the file). it installs fine (NO Errors generated, also get displayed in Installed Updates) but my dlls and .exe files **do not get updated.**

so how can i make this install with `REINSTALL=ALL`? is there a command i can add to the patch.wxs file?

thanks in advance

**Edit**

```
<CustomAction Id="PatchInstall" Property="PATCH" Value="REINSTALL" />
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="PatchInstall" Before="InstallInitialize">REINSTALL="ALL"</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

**Update on this - 2012/09/27**

The suggested method did not work but the problem with my solution is the file version did not change therefore the installer displays warning message advising that files have not changed. i found this in the log when installing the patch:

```
MSI (s) (48:F4) [17:32:34:025]: File: C:\Muzi_Test_Installer\ACME.dll;  Won't Overwrite;    Won't patch;    Existing file is of an equal version
```

so i'm going to update the file version and re-run the test.

**Final Update**
okay just to confirm this was a file versioning issue! just by updating the file version the MSP installs fine with no problem.

Comment: okay just to confirm this was a file versioning issue! just by updating the file version the MSP installs fine with no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to set `REINSTALL` property to `ALL` if the patch is being installed.

So you need to modify your new package and add a new custom action which changes `REINSTALL` value conditioned on [`PATCH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370576%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property.

**Edit:** You want your custom action to work this way:

```
if (PATCH) {
    REINSTALL = "ALL";
}
```

So in WiX, it looks as:

```
<CustomAction Id="PatchInstall" Property="REINSTALL" Value="ALL" />
<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="PatchInstall" Before="InstallInitialize">PATCH</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: okay thanks for kindly getting back to me, will try this out and revert back to you.

Comment: as you've suggested I've added a custom action with `REINSTALL` its NOT giving me the results i want, please will u kindly have a look at my settings to see if they look correct? thanks

Comment: @superbDeveloper You made it the other way round, your custom action does the following, in pseudo C code: `if (REINSTALL == "ALL") { PATCH = "REINSTALL"; }`. I've added the corrected code to my answer.

Comment: I finally tested and it didn't work but i found the issue, and it had to do with file version. Thanks for tho kindly assisting.

Answer (score 0):

Posting because I didn't see this potential fix listed --

I'm a bit surprised that the command-line directive succeeded in replacing the file if it had the same version number. The REINSTALLMODE directive "o---" should mean that ONLY files that are of a lesser version will be reinstalled.

Anyways, I think this issue could have also been addressed by changing the MSI installer's internal setting of REINSTALLMODE to be "a---" instead. The 'a' REINSTALLMODE attribute indicates that all files should be reinstalled, regardless of version or checksum.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30139475)